# how to find average with strings c#

Tags: c#, string, winforms, math, datagridview

I need to set a variable as the average of 3 other variables, which are numbers but they are set as strings. How do I do this? I'm using c#, visual studio, windows forms.

The variable i'm trying to set is called skiTime, the variables i'm using to get the average are called skiTime1, skiTime2 and skiTime3.

basically i need the c# version of: skiTime = (skiTime1 + skiTime2 + skiTime3) / 3

The code where I start (declare? I don't know the word to use) the variables

```
    List<string> skiTime1 = new List<string>();
    List<string> skiTime2 = new List<string>();
    List<string> skiTime3 = new List<string>();
    string skiTime
```

The code where i set the value for the variables:

```
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("pupilSkiTimes.txt"))
        {

            string line = "";
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] components = line.Split("~".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                skiTime1.Add(components[2]);
                skiTime2.Add(components[3]);
                skiTime3.Add(components[4]);
            }
            sr.Close();
        }
```

I need to display skiTime1, skiTime2 and skiTime3 in a data grid view, so i think they need to be strings, if i'm not mistaken. skiTime will only be used in another calculation so maybe it can be turned into an int. I don't really know what i'm doing and only got this far because of tutorials, help.

I can post the whole code if this question is too confusing or doesn't have enough information.

Comment: it's not perfectly clear to me why skiTime (1,2,3) are declared as list<string> if they are supposed to be string. But if they were string, you could convert them to Int32 doing something like: Int32.Parse(skiTime1); and then you were able to perform arithmetic operations on those data.

Comment: A DataGridView is absolutely capable to show integers or other types. But your problems seems to be elsewhere. What is the data present in a line? And a List<T> could have more than one value added. Are you trying to get the average of the values present in each list? Or an average of the values present in all three lists together?

Comment: Lists can store allot of ski times - why do you need three lists?

Comment: in the first part of question you talk about variables, in the last part you dealing with files. please clarify your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     public string CalculateAverage(List<string> skiTime1, List<string> skiTime2, List<string> skiTime3)
    {
        List<string> allValues = new List<string>();
        allValues.AddRange(skiTime1);
        allValues.AddRange(skiTime2);
        allValues.AddRange(skiTime3);
        float totalcount = 0;
        float average = 0;

        foreach (var value in allValues)
        {
            totalcount = totalcount + float.Parse(value);
        }

        average = totalcount / allValues.Count();
        return average.ToString();
    }
```

Function for returning the average value
Now call the function where u need like:

```
 string skiTime = CalculateAverage(skiTime1, skiTime2, skiTime3);
```

Comment: I'm getting an Invalid Cast Exception error when trying to convert this variable into a decimal, what does that mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the times include decimal points, e.g 21.43 or 22.56

Comment: Make floats of the "totalcount" and "average" variables and instead of an int.Parse(value) do an float.Parse(value).

Comment: I've updated my answer for you :)

Comment: For some reason the letters "NaN" are appearing in the text file instead of the average, I don't know why that's happening but what does it mean, how do I fix it

Comment: actually i think i should ask this as a seperate question

Comment: NaN stands for Not a Number. Check the strings that should contain these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the `strings` to `decimals` then calculate the average:

```
List<decimal> avgTime = new List<decimal>();
for (var i = 0; i < skiTime1.Length; i++) {
  var avg = (decimal.Parse(skiTime1[i]) + decimal.Parse(skiTime2[i]) + decimal.Parse(skiTime3[i])) / 3;
  avgTime.Add(avg);
}
```